# Why is the Apple AppStore in-app receipt empty on iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, receipt, receipt-validation

In application I need to implement auto-renewable subscriptions purchases.
As I understand documentation, I should check AppStore receipt on app launch and then validate that receipt with my server.
In my code I do following to retrieve receipt:

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
```

Sometimes `receipt` is becoming nil.
For example:

- I've launched an app and made purchase. After that the code above returns non empty `receipt`.
- App is stopped with Xcode.
- On next app launch `receipt` is nil.

I do not understand, why this happens. `receiptURL` points to file with receipt, but `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL]` returns nil.

If I request receipt refresh, then app shows dialog for entering Itunes credentials. This is not good, because this dialog will appear on app launch and this is unexpected behavior.

Am I doing something wrong? 
Or maybe this is sandbox-specific case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In production there will always be a receipt (even if the app is free), that can contain your additional purchase, in case you have bought something or restored from an already purchased item.
In test environment until you buy something the receipt is `nil`, if you want to test a case close to production, you should first try a restore (now you will have a receipt) and do what you need.

Comment: Thanks, Andrea! But I've already tried to restore purchases. After that receipt is not empty. But then I stop app with XCode and on next app launch receipt is nil.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8954) it is suggested that your payment procedure is being hacked, by calling the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased regardless. You need to validate the receipt on a server before accepting any receipts. 
You can find a great description of receipts and hacks [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/receipt-validation/).